# Coldfusion WebService Created from Create Object - Change Address Location

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, wsdl

I have created a ColdFusion web service from a WSDL file. I'd like to programmatically change the address location (web service end point) because it contains an end point that may be different for each of my clients. Is this possible within ColdFusion?

For example, the WSDL has the address location specified as:

```
<wsdlsoap:address location="URL TO NON CONSTANT LOCATION"/>
```

And I would like to do something like the following in my ColdFusion script.

```
<cfscript>
    myWebService = createObject( "webservice", "URL TO MY WEB SERVICE" );
    // This is where I'm stuck
    myWebService.setAddressLocation("NON CONSTANT URL TO CLIENT SPECIFIC END POINT");
</cfscript>
```

I've considered having different WSDL files for the different clients, but I'd like to avoid that because the location is the only item in the WSDL that would change.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest putting all the client related logic into the cfc with the webservice code.

Comment: Thanks Dan. That's exactly what I was planning to do. I'll be using a CFC that contains the API's business logic, but wanted to take advantage ColdFusion's ability to create a callable object from the WSDL file so that I did not have to create, send, and process SOAP requests and responses within my CFC. I found the answer after doing a bit more digging, and will be adding it shortly.

Answer (score 2):

I did a bit more digging, and found the object that needed to be updated within the ColdFusion web service wrapper. You can use the following to change address location.

```
<cfscript>
    myWebService = createObject( "webservice", "URL TO MY WEB SERVICE" );
    myWebService._getServiceClient().getOptions().getTo().setAddress("NON CONSTANT URL TO CLIENT SPECIFIC END POINT");
</cfscript>
```